# Iam getting the below warnings when i do 'ionic cordova build android --prod'

Tags: android, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

> '''
> Configure project :app
> WARNING: The onesignal-gradle-plugin MUST be before com.android.application!
> Please put onesignal-gradle-plugin first OR update to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 or newer!
> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 21.0.6113669.
> Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 21.0.6113669.

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See [https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings'''](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings%27%27%27)

config.xml

```
<widget id="io.ionic.crittr" version="1.2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Crittr</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="0.1.9" />
    <plugin name="mx.ferreyra.callnumber" spec="~0.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="2.8.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.6.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="5.0.0" />
    <plugin name="com-badrit-base64" spec="0.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" spec="2.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder" spec="^3.4.1" />
    <plugin name="com.razorpay.cordova" spec="1.4.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^3.0.2" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.4" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8101" sessionid="d499ffe6" />
</widget>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "crittrfinal",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/base64": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/uid": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@logisticinfotech/ionic-timepicker": "^1.0.3",
    "call-number": "1.0.1",
    "com-badrit-base64": "0.2.0",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.2.5",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "^1.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.8",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ios-location-permissions": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-uid": "1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.6.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ion2-calendar": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
    "ionic": "^5.4.16",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "~0.0.2",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "2.8.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.10.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.1.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "com.razorpay.cordova": "^1.4.11",
    "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly.",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly.",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "com-badrit-base64": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
        "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "call-number": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs camera access",
        "MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs microphone access",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs write-access to photo library",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs read/write-access photo library access"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "com.razorpay.cordova": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser",
      "ios"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "gtoken": "4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/440#issuecomment-457996731

You might find this handy. Looks like you aren't the only one running into this issue . Let me know if this helps.

It looks like it may have to do with Gradle.

Comment: ohk no problem i will check